# Issue with get product attribute value in other place than list.phtml

Tags: magento2, slider, variables, mageplaza

Currently via below code I can get in `list.phtml`

From this I get brand name dropdown value in list.phtml correct:

```
<div class="brand-name"> <?php 
            $optionText = '';
            $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand');

            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
               $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getBrand());
            }
            ?>
            <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                 <?php echo "" . $optionText . "<br>"; ?>
            <?php } ?></div>
```

via this code I get text subname in list.phtml

```
<div class="subname">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('subname')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('<br /><br />') ?></div>
```

Now I try also display this attributes in custom slider:

```
app/code/Mageplaza/Productslider/view/frontend/templates/productslider.phtml
```

But When I put this code then sliders dissapper. I try add variable to this file:

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productModel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
?>
```

But still no work. Can anyone help me?

This file mageplaza slider file:
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-product-slider/blob/2.4/view/frontend/templates/productslider.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this below code inside foreach in that file :

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('subname')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item); ?>
```

Comment: great we got it! Could you please help us as well, can we similarly get the value from the dropdown? (this is  first code in our topic with brand name) - can you help us rewrite it?

Comment: Try with pass dropdown attribute code instead of subname.

Comment: have you do some customs? If Yes can you Please share for me your contact details ? I have one question.